# Help Calculating the Length of a Helical Wire Coil

Tags: physics, parametrization

Hello can someone please help explain the following:

A very thin wire is coiled N times to form a solenoid of length  H. The radius is R. What length of wire should you  purchase? Use the azimuthal angle to parameterize the helix

I know the answer to this problem and how to solve for L, I just don't understand how I would parameterize this problem such that the answer is as follows: gamma=R, azimuthal angle= t and z=(H/N)(t/2pi) (the answer)

can someone please help explain this, sorry for the bad formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the parameterization $$ x=R\cos t, y=R\sin t, z = (H/N)(t/{2\pi })$$

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, how does z=(H/N)(t/2π)?

Comment: every $2\pi $ units of time we have one turn. In N turns 
 the height is H.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this, this makes a lot of sense now!